# Getting Object null refrence Error on login in asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I want To Make one Login Page For Members And Admin Also..
Here I have done the Following Code as:

**In Model:**

```
   public class Login
        {
             public int ID { get; set; }
             public string UserName { get; set; }
             public string Password { get; set; }
        }
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login login, MemberDetailsWrapper memberlogin)
{
    WrapperDB db = new WrapperDB();
    if (login.UserName.Equals("admin") &&login.Password.Equals("admin"))     //This will check for admin
    {
           returnRedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else if
    (
        (login.UserName.Equals(memberlogin.objMemberBasicInformation.MemberFirstName.Equals(db.MemberBasicInformationDBS.Where(a =>a.MemberFirstName.Equals(a.MemberFirstName))))
        && (login.Password.Equals(memberlogin.objMemberBasicInformation.Qualification.Equals(db.MemberBasicInformationDBS.Where(a=>a.Qualification.Equals(a.Qualification))))))
    )
//This is For Member Login When Member Enter His FistName as a userName and Qualification as Password then Both credential match with the data present in db and return the respected person information
    {
           return RedirectToAction("Index","MemberDetails");
    }               
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName And Password is Incorrect!!");
    return View();
}
```

**In view :**

```
<%@PageTitle=""Language="C#"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHGManagementProject.Models.Login>"%>

<h2>Login</h2>
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  { %>
<%:Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
<legend>Log in Form</legend>
<div>
UserName
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName) %>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
        Password
<%:Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password) %>
</div>
<br/>

<div>
<inputid="SubmitLogin"type="submit"value="Login"/>
<%--<%:Html.ActionLink("Are you Member? click Here!!","Login","Account") %>--%>
</div>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

On execution When i Enter the Username and Pass as admin then it will perform successfully.. but when i enter the another username and password then it throws Error **NullReferenceException was Unhandled by User code**

please tell me the solution and help me to solve this

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see where you're getting the error?

Comment: See [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Most likely any of `memberlogin.objMemberBasicInformation.MemberFirstName` is `null`.

Comment: point out the line that caused the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing where your code is throwing the error, I'm assuming the issue is down to `memberLogin` parameter?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login login, MemberDetailsWrapper memberlogin)
{
    WrapperDB db = new WrapperDB();
    if (login.UserName.Equals("admin") &&login.Password.Equals("admin"))     //This will check for admin
    {
           returnRedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else if (memberlogin != null)
    {
       if   
        (
            (login.UserName.Equals(memberlogin.objMemberBasicInformation.MemberFirstName.Equals(db.MemberBasicInformationDBS.Where(a =>a.MemberFirstName.Equals(a.MemberFirstName))))
            && (login.Password.Equals(memberlogin.objMemberBasicInformation.Qualification.Equals(db.MemberBasicInformationDBS.Where(a=>a.Qualification.Equals(a.Qualification))))))
        )
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Index","MemberDetails");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName And Password is Incorrect!!");
            return View();
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName And Password is Incorrect!!");
    return View();
}
```

I've added a check against `memberlogin` to check if it's `null`, double check the parenthesis though, as I've just typed this by hand.